# HTTP Status 404 when deploying the project on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, spring, maven

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/) and want to compile Spring-Ajax project from Eclipse. This is [the Git link](https://github.com/mkyong/spring4-mvc-ajax-example) of the project: 
I was able to compile and deploy this project as Jetty instance using:

```
mvn:jetty run
```

Now I need to deploy it to my Tomcat 8 server. To do this, I follow usual steps that always worked with other projects: Eclipse -> Run as -> Maven build, start Server, got to localhost:8080/appName. I also added the project to the Server.

However for this particular project I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /spring4ajax
```

This is the `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring4-mvc-maven-ajax-example</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring4 mvc maven ajax example</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>3.1.0</servletapi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for views -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- compile only, deployed container will provide this -->
        <!-- Need this for config annotation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version> -->
<!--                <configuration> -->
<!--                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds> -->
<!--                    <webApp> -->
<!--                        <contextPath>/spring4ajax</contextPath> -->
<!--                    </webApp> -->
<!--                </configuration> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>spring4ajax</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Deploy to WildFly -->
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>1.1.0.Alpha5</version> -->
<!--                <configuration> -->
<!--                    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname> -->
<!--                    <port>9990</port> -->
<!--                    <username>admin</username> -->
<!--                    <password>admin</password> -->
<!--                    <name>etur.war</name> -->
<!--                </configuration> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: why is the jetty plugin that configures /spring4ajax commented out?

Comment: @radai: I tried both options: with and without jetty dependency. The goal is to deploy this app on Tomcat, not as a jetty instance. So far I am unable to do this.